# Going back to a page gives the original page

Tags: ajax, caching

If i feed a page to a user, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        function cbCountry_Click()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById("cbCountry");

            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("Canada", "CA");
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("United States", "US");
        }​
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <SELECT id="cbCountry"></SELECT>
    <P><BUTTON onclick="cbCountry_Click()">Get Countries</BUTTON>
    <P><A href="http://google.com">Visit a link</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This page has the capability to modify itself. In this case it's standalone javascript, but imagine it's AJAX code.

[image]

If the user then clicks a link to go *forward*, then clicks to return *back* to this page; they will be presented with the page as it is cached; rather than how they left it:

[image]

Has anyone solved the AJAX problem?

---

i notice that Google periodically sends the state of your page to the server. If you return to the page they force a timer refresh, which refreshes the state of the page from the server.

i've also noticed that some people simply force the page to not be cached:

```
Cache-Control: nocache
```

preventing the page from being cached. Downside of that is that it prevents the page from being cached.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie to store the state on the client side and restore the state of the page from the cookie whenever your page is loaded.